# Caffe runtest fails glog is statically and dynamically linked

Tags: caffe

I have the following error when I make caffe: make runtest -j8

```
ERROR: something wrong with flag 'logtostderr' in file '/glog/src/logging.cc'.  One possibility: file '/glog/src/logging.cc' is being linked both statically and dynamically into this executable.
```

I am not sure how to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have 2 versions of libgflags.

```
#Remove libgflags:
sudo apt-get remove -y libgflags-dev

# Check the path first before proceeding:
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a /usr/local/lib/libgflags_nothreads.a
sudo rm -rf  /usr/local/include/gflags

#Reinstall it:
sudo apt-get install -y libgflags-dev

Rebuild caffe
```

Comment: I tried that before, and it didnt fix anything... first thing, it couldnt find libgflags so did not remove it. if I use libgflags-dev instead it removes it

Comment: In this case, you need to provide more info, so we can provide a more relevant answer. The error just says that you have 2 versions of libgflags, now, since you haven't provide more info, it's your job to find out where you installed them and how to fix the issue.

Comment: @LiviuStefan I got error: { make: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/include/gflags/gflags.h', needed by '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.o'.  Stop.  }  after did the way you post. Could you further advise? Thanks!